# Does good documentation for the Python codecs framework exist that covers what is not in the official documentaion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, codec, python-internals

The Python codecs framework, implemented mostly the codecs module of the standard library, has a large number of little tweaks.   While digging through the source code is possible, I keep finding new rules:

- Any codec name prefixed with 'utf-8', e.g., 'utf-8-with-my-modification' is grabbed by the utf-8 decoder, though this logic isn't in `lib\python3.8\encodings\alias.py` or anywhere else I can find.
- In order to make an encoder function with `open` or `codecs.open`, you must set `._is_text_encoding` to True or set that parameter in your `get_registry()` call.

But I keep getting more and more questions:

- Can I add to the search path for codecs beyond the built-in `lib\python3.8\encodings` directory?
- Are the first two lines of a file re-decoded after the `coding=` regex is met?
- Is there a better way to have one file provide multiple codecs for `coding=` lines than using a bunch of symbolic links and looking at `__FILE__`?
- What makes an minimum viable codec?  It seems to need one-shot (stateless) and incremental coder/decoders, but default stream implementations are fine?
- Is there a comparison of the available subclasses to Codec that seem to provide different functionality?

Really, I am looking for a good reference, set of papers, strategic design document, or other in-depth treatment of the Python Codecs.   Right now, I have source code, conflicting beginner tutorials on writing your own codecs, and many accounts of people giving up.

I know the question seems open-ended, and I'm not new to StackOverflow.  This is an Infrequently Answered Question.

Comment: Most of your bullet points seem inaccurate, already documented, or not actually the responsibility of the codec system. For example, `coding` lines are just one of the places where Python uses codecs; they're not actually part of the codec system itself.

Comment: Assuming your first bullet point is about `coding` comments, the "utf-8" weirdness is implemented [in the tokenizer](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.0/Parser/tokenizer.c#L119), rather than in any part of the codec system.

Comment: In general, we should avoid relying on implementation details (though sometimes we have to know them: [Hyrum's Law](https://www.hyrumslaw.com/)) -- they may change at any moment. If a behavior should be preserved then it should be documented. https://devguide.python.org/docquality/